# regular expression: Efficiency of case insensitive comparsion

Tags: regex

Given a pattern p and a string s, suppose p is in lower case.  Which of the following two is more efficient?

```
r = re.compile(r'p', RE.IGNORECASE)
r.match(s)
```

... or ...

```
r = re.compile(r'p')
r.match(s.lower())
```

Comment: We're assuming that the pattern is all lower case for #2, right? Otherwise, they're not equivalent

Comment: In the time it took you to type this question you could have benchmarked this and have gotten a better, more accurate answer to your question.

Comment: @ryeguy, By what do you mean "benchmarked"?

Comment: @Paul: You could have wrapped each of these in a block of code that times the execution of each so you could have seen exactly which function is faster and by how much.

Comment: @Paul: What do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really going to depend on the language and engine.  `s.lower()` and `re.IGNORECASE` are generally only slow because they're trying to deal with localization or Unicode strings (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010/is-regex-case-insensitivity-slower)).  If the regex package you're using deals with that, and the `s.lower()` method doesn't, then the `s.lower()` method is a clear win.  And vice-versa.

In general, I'd expect the `s.lower()` method to be faster (it tends to be more optimized than regex matching).  But in the example as given ...

```
r = re.compile(r'[Pp]')
r.match(s)
```

... is going to be faster than either of them.

Comment: This is twice as faster then IGNORECASE, thank you!
`1.2s` versus `660ms` on sample data.